# How could I generate random convex polygons of area 1?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, geometry, code-request

How could you random convex polygons where the points of the graph

$A(x_1,y_1) , B(x_2,y_2), ... $

come out, hopefully in rational format (a/b) in such a way that the total area of ​​the polygon is always be 1.
The ranges for the x axis would be from -5 to 5 and the y axis from 0 to 5.

something like what is shown in the following code but that the x axis and also the y axis come out, but only the positive part, at least one stroke should rest on the x axis

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

randompoly := Module[{poly},
  While[Length[FindIntersections[
     poly = PolygonCombine @ SimplePolygonPartition @
     Polygon[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}]]]] > 0];
  poly]

 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, randompoly}]
```

(********)

```
 Table[Graphics[p, ImageSize -> 100], {p, 
 RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 5}, 3]}]
```

edit

It seems I didn't explain well

a) The points can be integers, but if they are decimal, the ideal would be to represent them in the form p/q, to ​​avoid representing them in a periodic or semi-periodic form.

b) the polygon must have at least one side on the x-axis, the polygon must be positioned for all "y" greater than or equal to zero

c) the points of the polygon must be in the vertices of the figure

Comment: While generating any random polygon of area 1 isn't that complicated, generating one with rational number coordinates in its vertices seems like it'll be quite a bit more of a challenge. Picking uniformly from that possibility space seems much more difficult yet, if that is of any interest to you.

Comment: If it is alright that the area can be 1 plus a tiny numerical error like 0.9999999999999998, then similarly to the answer by cvgmt, you could may use `unscaledPts = {{0, 0}}~Join~{{RandomReal[{-5, 5}], 0}}~Join~Transpose[{RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3], RandomReal[{0, 5}, 3]}];`

Comment: **then** `unscaledPoly=Polygon[unscaledPts]`

Comment: **then** `scaledPts = unscaledPts/Sqrt[Area[unscaled˘poly]] // Rationalize[#, 0] &`;

Comment: **then** `poly=Polygon[scaledPts]`.

Comment: I did not include the labeling of the points in `Graphics`

Comment: This question reminds me of Bertrand's paradox. What do you mean by a "random" polygon? For any n>2, I'd guess at most a finite number of n-gons meet your criteria (rational vertices, area=1, bounded by a 10x5 rectangle); but there are infinite choices for n; thus Bertand applies. Furthermore, for any specific n, a "random n-gon" would (I assume) be a random choice from all those that exist. Algorithms to produce such n-gons surely exist, but a sequence of "random" choices during production does not guarantee that the result is a "random n-gon."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

- We construct some random integer coordinate points which contain `{0,0}` and `{c,0}`.
- select the convex polygons which have the integer square area.
- scaling the polygon respect to the origin `{0,0}` by the factor `λ = 1/Sqrt[Area[reg]]`

```
SeedRandom[123];
Clear[data, regs, reg, λ, pts];
n = 14;
data := Block[{c = RandomInteger[{0, 10}]}, 
   Join[{{0, 0}, {c, 0}}, 
    Thread[{RandomInteger[{c, c + 10}, n], 
      RandomInteger[{0, 20}, n]}]]];
regs = Table[ConvexHullMesh[data], 200];
reg = Pick[regs, IntegerQ[Sqrt[Area@#]] & /@ regs][[1]];
λ = 1/Sqrt[Area[reg]];
pts = MeshPrimitives[reg, 1][[;; , 1, 1]];
pts = λ*pts;
Polygon[pts] // Area
Graphics[{{Opacity[.5], Cyan, Polygon[pts]}, {Red, 
   Point[pts]}, {Brown, Text[#, #, {-1, -1}] & /@ pts}}, Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

> `1`

[image]

Comment: (It is possible that at least one of the sides of the polygon breaks from the x axis, in addition that each execution generates another random polygon.)

Answer (score 4):

*The first part of this answer ignores the condition that one edge must be aligned with the $x$-axis, for simplicity. To include this condition, see the comment at the end of this post.*

This uses `RandomPolygon`, then rationalizes the coordinates, then rescales to set the area equal to $1$. Unlike the other answer, it rescales $x$ and $y$ components by two different (but approximately equal) rational numbers:

```
randomUnitAreaConvexRational[n_,dx_:1/10000] :=
  With[{c=Rationalize[RandomPolygon[{"Convex",n}][[1]],dx]},
    With[{a=Area[Polygon[c]]},
      With[{b=Rationalize[Sqrt[a],dx]},
        Polygon[c.{{1/b,0},{0,b/a}}]]]];
```

**Example.**

```
SeedRandom[123];
P = randomUnitAreaConvexRational[11];

MatchQ[P[[1]],{{_?ExactNumberQ..}..}]
(* True *)

Area[P]
(* 1 *)

RegionPlot[P]
```

[image]

**Comment.** To align one edge with the $x$-axis, replace `RandomPolygon` with `randomPolygon` in the code above, where

```
randomPolygon[args___] :=
  With[{c=RandomPolygon[args][[1]]},
    With[{r=RotationMatrix[{c[[2]]-c[[1]],{1,0}}]},
      Polygon[N[Chop[Map[r.(#-c[[1]])&,c]]]]]];
```

Comment: Very nice idea of using the liberty to use two scales to enforce both the rationality of the coordinates and the the perfect unit area of the polygon. +1